# Does Set-Location see "Traverse/Execute" NTFS permissions?

Tags: windows, powershell

Set-Location fails when attempting to access a directory that's beneath a folder that the user doesn't have any defined NTFS access permissions.

Granting at least List folder / read data to parent Share allows traversal, and enumeration of Folder1, but you cannot use Set-location to change the PWD (Access Denied) without this. This is true even though you can access Folder1 without issue via Explorer or the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\Server\Share\Folder1" succeeds 
Set-Location "\\Server\Share\Folder1" fails
```

Edit: Evidently it is possible to use Set-Location on directories lower than Folder 1.

```
Set-Location "\\Server\Share\Folder1\Folder2" succeeds
```

It appears that Set-Location doesn't allow you to set the pwd to the first nested folder without list/read permissions on the share.

How is this behavior explained?

Edit: This behavior only occurs when using UNC it, functions as expected when using Drive Letters.

Comment: Listing a directory requires read-data access. Setting it as the working directory requires synchronize and execute access. That said, users can traverse a directory to a file or subdirectory regardless of access to the directory because they have SeChangeNotifyPrivilege, which is default enabled.

Comment: Apparently, an internal [`SetLocation`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/v6.1.2/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/SessionStateLocationAPIs.cs#L196) function first tries to normalize the path via `NormalizeRelativePath`, which in the UNC case tries to list the parent directory to get the normalized casing of the name (e.g. "FOLDER1" -> "Folder1"). This fails if we don't have read access for the directory, and apparently they just rethrow the exception instead of handling it as they obviously should (i.e. this is a bug).